# How to push item values to extreme top/bottom in selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am researching and testing with forms. So far, I succeeded in moving items in select box list up and down one by one with [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shobhit_Sharma/b7Yct/2/).

Instance of code (to move up):

```
function moveUp() {
$("#list-box option:selected").each(function () {
    var listItem = $(this);
    var listItemPosition = $("#list-box option").index(listItem) + 1;

    if (listItemPosition == 1) return false;

    listItem.insertBefore(listItem.prev());
  });
}
```

But now I need to move a selected value, either to be at extreme top in the list or at very bottom. Please try to experiment up with this fiddle and suggest me possible [jQuery tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) method if it applies.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move it to the very top:

```
    var listItem = $(this);
    listItem.insertBefore(listItem.siblings().first());
```

To move it to the very bottom:

```
    var listItem = $(this);
    listItem.insertBefore(listItem.siblings().last());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cYw6R/

Answer (score 4):

Use [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) and [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
function moveTop(){
     $('#list-box option:selected').prependTo('#list-box');
}

function moveBottom(){
     $('#list-box option:selected').appendTo('#list-box');
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Yct/10/)

Comment: Way more efficient than my answer. I'll leave mine for educational purposes, though.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/b7Yct/7/

You need to change your insertBefore and insertAfter statement to insert before the first option and after the last option.

```
function moveUp() {
$("#list-box option:selected").each(function () {
    var listItem = $(this);
    var listItemPosition = $("#list-box option").index(listItem) + 1;

    if (listItemPosition == 1) return false;

    listItem.insertBefore($("#list-box option:first"));
});
}

function moveDown() {
var itemsCount = $("#list-box option").length;

$($("#list-box option:selected").get().reverse()).each(function () {
    var listItem = $(this);
    var listItemPosition = $("#list-box option").index(listItem) + 1;

    if (listItemPosition == itemsCount) return false;

    listItem.insertAfter($("#list-box option:last"));
});
}
```